# Roughness broken in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, roughness

I can't get comparable results between Eevee and Substance. The texture maps always look way too shiny.

I've used the Principled Shader quite a bit and know all its nuances (non-color data for the channels that need it, ect.)

Here are some screenshots of my issue. I'd love to know why I can't get this to work. Any help here would be much appreciated! Thanks.

[image: Substance Designer Roughness]

[image: Eevee Roughness]

[image: Graph]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[image]OK SO... I forgot that Blender doesn't like .png files. Avoid them and everything shows up fine. -__-

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that comes across this, I don't think PNGs are the culprit. Instead, if you change the interpolation from Linear (default) to Closest, it should look about as close as it can to Cycles.

[image: Interpolation Set to Closest]